# Amount of chests in Dungeon World?

Tags: dungeon-world, treasure

I wanted to ask a question about chests and loot in general.
There is a table in the DW rulebook where you can roll if you think a monster has a chest with it.
I noticed that the amount of coins is quite high if you compare it with the other list in the book that is about treasures from specific monsters like an orc hort.
How do you all handle this?

Comment: Welcome! Could you provide a link or a reference to where you found this table?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. The "how do you all handle this" phrasing makes this sound like a survey question, but I'm guessing you're actually asking how the rule/table is meant to be interpreted.

Answer (score 2):

### "Tribute" doesn't mean "total treasure".

So, an orc warchief's tribute, from the "equipment" chapter, is 250 coin, but from the "monsters" chapter, the treasure you'd roll up for one (best of 2d10 plus 2 as damage, probably +1d4 for being lord over others) can include multiple possibilities, among them getting a 9 and getting a chest of miscellaneous valuables weighing 1 and worth about 1000 (3d6x100) coin.

Why the difference? These are measuring **two different things**. "Tribute" can best be understood as "wealth presented to a powerful figure to represent something significant". 250 coin is sufficiently pricey to make an impression on an orc warchief, perhaps as leverage for Parley. The other entries under "hoards" in the equipment chapter are likewise there to help you decide what other creatures consider a significant amount of money, absent any greater personal relevance.

For example, a handful of silver, 10 coin or so, is a great fortune to a goblin, a notable sum to a lizardman, a meager insult to an orc warchief, and a rounding error to a dragon. But if the Star Sapphire of the Sapphire Star is a mark of significance among the blue dragons, it will be important to a blue dragon, regardless of what some gnomish jeweler might value it at compared to a dragon's hoard.

Comment: Surely a Dragon, being a Cautious Hoarder, would not accept rounding error when it comes to its hoard. +1 anyway.